# How to move a website to a new server?

Tags: ubuntu, rsync, directory, ubuntu-18.04, scp

I am going to move my website to a new server.

I need to copy the `/var/www` directory to the new server.

Should I use SCP or RSYNC ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use either SCP or Rsync, they will both copy files for what you need.

For the following example, assume the following:

- Your username on www1.example.com is jcitizen.
- Your old web server is www1.example.com.
- Your new web server is www2.example.com.
- jcitizen on the old server has read permissions recursively on /var/www
- The user on the new server has read & write permissions recursively on /var/www

**SCP**

```
scp -r jcitizen@www1.example.com:/var/www /var/www
```

**RSYNC**

```
rsync -avzh jcitizen@www1.example.com:/var/www /var/www
```